# cmi.exit data model element

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

- Root

  - Activity 1
  - Activity 2
  - Activity 3

Suppose that Activity 2 is launched. Activity 2 sets "cmi.exit" to "suspend" and "adl.nav.request" to "exitAll" and the calls Terminate(""). What should be happened next? I want to know if current Activity Tree State should be persisted in the next Sequencing Session? Which Activity should be delivered in the next Sequencing Session?

Answer (score 2):

"exitAll" will terminate the whole course and logically all activities will not be available and tracking data is not saved. If you want to retain tracking data for the whole course, you have to use "suspendAll" instead. Setting "cmi.exit" to "suspend" saves the tracking data for the current activity only. 
"Resume" will not be available in the example you mentiond since no tracking data has been saved.

Comment: What about the Activity 2's run-time data (e.g., cmi.interactions, cmi.objectives, cmi.suspend_data, etc.)? Will this information of Activity 2 accessible in the next Sequencing Session?